# Gitkraken doesn't understand gitignore

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore, gitkraken

I have generated a Laravel project with all the .gitignore files.
I put some images in the `storage\app\public` folder which I don't want to push.
Gitkraken offers the option to stage this files, but they are in the .gitignore like this:

```
*
!public/
!.gitignore
```

(This is in the `storage\app\public` folder)

`VSCode` sees this, and doesn't offer the option to stage which is fine, but Gitkraken does.
If I right click on the folder and select `Ignore all files in \storage` is not an option because that way adds a new line to my top-level gitignore file for ignoring the `\storage` folder which I don't want.

Comment: When i try it it works. Are you sure that the files you are trying to ignore has not yet already been added to the repository (i.e. are they "new" or "modified" files)?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, VSCode successfully ignores the files, but GitKraken sees them as unstaged